# How to find a number with one or more digits using a regular expression find in UltraEdit?

Tags: regex, ultraedit

I use the regular expression search string `amzn-src-id="[0-9]"` in UltraEdit, but the result is that found are only the numbers `1` to `9`, i.e. numbers with just one digit.

For example: `amzn-src-id="1"`, `amzn-src-id="2"`, `amzn-src-id="3"`, ..., `amzn-src-id="9"`

How to fix that?

I need to find strings like `amzn-src-id="4798"` with an identifier number with not only one digit.

Answer (score 1):

Use as search string `amzn-src-id="[0-9]+"` with `+` added to find any digit **one or more times**.

In UltraEdit for Windows the key <kbd>F1</kbd> can be pressed on opened **Find** / **Replace** / **Find in Files** / **Replace in Files** dialog window which opens the appropriate help page containing two links to two more help pages, one for **Regular Expressions** explaining completely UltraEdit and Unix regular expression syntax and one for **Perl Regular Expressions** explaining briefly Perl regular expression syntax.

And depending on version of UltraEdit for Windows there is above or right to *Find what* and *Replace with* edit area a graphic button with a magnifying glass (UE ≥ v21.10) or a triangle (UE v16.00 to v21.00) which opens a list showing suitable regular expressions for the find or replace string with brief explanation. Clicking on an item in this list inserts the expression at current position of caret in find or replace string. This feature is called **regular expression builder** and is designed for users who are beginners in using regular expressions.